# В чем разница между «отыскать» и «искать»?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Я должна **отыскать способ** справиться с возникшей проблемой.
>
> Я должна **искать способ** справиться с возникшей проблемой.

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению один отличается от другого?

Answer (score 3):

Глагол **отыскать** (совершенного вида) заключает в себе смысл *результативности* действия (искать + найти), а глагол несовершенного вида **искать** обозначает только *процесс* поиска. Поэтому во втором предложении сочетание "*должна искать*" звучит менее естественно: "должна" скорее подразумевает *результат*, особенно если требование исходит от кого-то другого. Но вполне возможно "*мне нужно/придётся искать*" (результат тоже неясен, но акцент - на использование *шанса* найти путём поиска).